# How to deal with dependent integration test classes?

Tags: junit, integration-testing

I have two test classes: `PostIT` and `UserIT`. Test cases in both classes make requests against the same server ([Spark](http://sparkjava.com)) and are dependent. I need the tests being executed like this:

1. Start server
2. Run `PostIT` tests
3. Stop server
4. Start server
5. Run `UserIT` tests
6. Stop server

Now, I have this:

```
class PostIT {

  @Before
  fun initialise() {
    startServer()    
  }

  @Test
  fun test1() {

  }

  //more test cases
}
```

---

```
class UserIT {

  @Before
  fun initialise() {
    startServer()    
  }

  @Test
  fun test1() {

  }

  //more test cases
}
```

Both classes are executed in parallel so I have some errors due to the dependencies between test cases.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Tests don't run in parallel by default. So change your configuration so that they don't run in parallel.